# In Apache, is the local path for ErrorDocument says in htdocs or domain in eclipse?

Tags: apache, path, httpd.conf, proxy-server, errordocument

In my case  Apache is a proxy server , is the local path for ErrorDocument says in htdocs or domain in eclipse? Because whenever I give path to this tag it always checks in eclipse but not in local path. How to make it work? Tried so many ways didn't worked out.